# [Solved]org-mode failing to export to html "Undefined Org macro: comment; aborting"

Tags: org-export

I copied my old org-mode file to a new Debian 9.x machine and it appears I may have missed something.

When I try to `C-c C-e h h` I see the following error

```
Undefined Org macro: comment; aborting
```

my previous setup did not have any Macros configured and I cannot seem to find this exact error looking around.  Previously I have never experienced an error in the export however the previously machine was Debian 8.x

I learned that html export works with other org files except the one that I want.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes across this error message - it turns out some text was added to my file and I am not sure how but essentially I found

```
{{{comment ()}}}
```

had been added around some text in two areas of my org file - I have no idea how it appeared there but I can only assume the newer version of emacs/org-mode created it.

In any case - I removed this new text and I was able to export to html again!